# Solving a complex number equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

I have this exercise:

Find the imaginary part of the solution whose real part is negative.

$z^2-2iz-\frac{1}{4}\left(5+i\sqrt{3}\right)=0$

I tried to factorize it and I came up with this:

$$\frac{8i\pm \sqrt{-16-4\times4\times(-5-i\sqrt3)}}{8}$$

Is it right? How can I complete the exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the quadratic formula, the roots of this equation are$$\frac{2i\pm\sqrt{1+\sqrt3i}}2=i\pm\frac12\sqrt{1+\sqrt3i}.$$But$$1+\sqrt3i=2\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)=2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)i\right)$$and therefore the square roots of $1+\sqrt3i$ are$$\pm\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi6\right)+\sin\left(\frac\pi6\right)i\right)=\pm\sqrt2\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac i2\right).$$Therefore, the solution whose real part is negative is$$-\sqrt2\frac{\sqrt3}4+i-\sqrt2\frac i4=-\sqrt{\frac38}+i-\frac i{\sqrt8}.$$

Comment: The solutions I am given are:$ 0,2,1-\frac{\sqrt2}{4},2+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$. Maybe I am blind, but does any of them coincide with yours, which is obviously correct?

Comment: @Evoked It's a quadratic equation. It can have no more than $2$ solutions.

Comment: Yes, but I am given those to choose only one of them(the correct answer)

Comment: @Evoked Then the answer is $1-\frac{\sqrt2}4$, of course, since it is equal to $1-\frac1{\sqrt8}$.

Comment: Know I get it, thank you so much and sorry for having to explain it so detailed!

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no. You must write $z=a+bi$; $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<0$. Put this into equation and do some calculation.

Comment: Okay, but know I have an equation with a,b and real and imaginary parts mixed. How do I get a solution from them?

Comment: $a^2+2abi-b^2-2ia+2b-\frac{1}{4}(5+i\sqrt3)=0$

Comment: Yes, but I would get $a^2-b^2+2b-\frac{5}{4}=i(-2ab+2a+\frac{1}{4}\sqrt3)$. And I honestly do not know how to continue.

Comment: Both sides must be equal to 0 since left side is real and left imaginary number.

Comment: Sorry for giving you so much work, but this is really hard for me to understand. Both of them are equal to zero, I get that. So I do a system of equations and solve for a and b, and then I get the solution?

Comment: Thanks and sorry once again